# What are some easy tips for accelerating SSL when using IIS?

Tags: iis, ssl, performance, iis-7.5

This evening while perusing Hacker News I came upon a post with the title [5 easy tips to accelerate SSL](http://unhandledexpression.com/2013/01/25/5-easy-tips-to-accelerate-ssl/). An interesting read, but I don't use Apache or Nginx and am instead interested in similar tips for IIS. Cursory Googling didn't turn up anything of note (doesn't mean I missed something). Are there similar "easy" tips for speeding up the way IIS handles SSL?

Answer (score 2):

The CDN stuff is software agnostic, so same advice.

[article discussion cache-control for IIS7](http://www.galcho.com/Blog/post/2008/02/27/IIS7-How-to-set-cache-control-for-static-content.aspx)

Intermediate certificates are presented by default, which is something every Apache and Nginx configuration should have anyway, so that one was a bit misleading.

[IIS7 Enable KeepAlive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772183%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Cypher Suite list in IIS is just about terrible to configure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030)